# Collision-free motion planning using OMPL in Moveit2

Tags: ros2, ompl, moveit2

I am using Moveit2 (ROS2 Humble) to plan a collision-free motion using a UR manipulator and planners from the OMPL available in Moveit2.

I have used [this tutorial](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/planning_around_objects/planning_around_objects.html) to spawn collision objects with the only difference - I have used non-primitive collision objects, that I have imported. Usually, the planner is able to plan a collision-free motion, however sometimes (rarely) the planner computes a path with a collision, look at the terminal output below:

```
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567525.449681527] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Received request
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567525.449740166] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: executing..
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567525.449768568] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567525.450330521] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'ur_manipulator[LazyPRMstarkConfigDefault]' will use planner 'geometric::LazyPRMstar'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-1] [ERROR] [1709567530.502879743] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Computed path is not valid. Invalid states at index locations: [ 10 11 12 13 14 ] out of 217. Explanations follow in command line. Contacts are published on /display_contacts
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567530.502963268] [moveit_collision_detection_fcl.collision_common]: Found a contact between 'pick_up_bin' (type 'Object') and 'wrist_3_link' (type 'Robot link'), which constitutes a collision. Contact information is not stored.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567530.502971533] [moveit_collision_detection_fcl.collision_common]: Collision checking is considered complete (collision was found and 0 contacts are stored)
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567530.503241003] [moveit_collision_detection_fcl.collision_common]: Found a contact between 'pick_up_bin' (type 'Object') and 'wrist_3_link' (type 'Robot link'), which constitutes a collision. Contact information is not stored.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567530.503249880] [moveit_collision_detection_fcl.collision_common]: Collision checking is considered complete (collision was found and 0 contacts are stored)
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567530.503304751] [moveit_collision_detection_fcl.collision_common]: Found a contact between 'pick_up_bin' (type 'Object') and 'wrist_3_link' (type 'Robot link'), which constitutes a collision. Contact information is not stored.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567530.503311664] [moveit_collision_detection_fcl.collision_common]: Collision checking is considered complete (collision was found and 0 contacts are stored)
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567530.503364352] [moveit_collision_detection_fcl.collision_common]: Found a contact between 'pick_up_bin' (type 'Object') and 'wrist_3_link' (type 'Robot link'), which constitutes a collision. Contact information is not stored.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567530.503371726] [moveit_collision_detection_fcl.collision_common]: Collision checking is considered complete (collision was found and 0 contacts are stored)
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567530.503444370] [moveit_collision_detection_fcl.collision_common]: Found a contact between 'pick_up_bin' (type 'Object') and 'wrist_3_link' (type 'Robot link'), which constitutes a collision. Contact information is not stored.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567530.503452576] [moveit_collision_detection_fcl.collision_common]: Collision checking is considered complete (collision was found and 0 contacts are stored)
[move_group-1] [ERROR] [1709567530.503504131] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Completed listing of explanations for invalid states.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1709567530.503826239] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Motion plan was found but it seems to be invalid (possibly due to postprocessing). Not executing.
```

So, I am curious why does it happen.

Could it be that that the clearance for the OMPL is too small that triggers the Moveit2 collision checker?

Is it possible to set the clearance for the OMPL planner in Moveit2?